# Range Error keeps appearing when dismissible widget is run

Tags: flutter

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(TodoList());

class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
// TODO: implement createState
return _TodoListState();
  }
}

var TaskTextField;
List taskTextList = [];
var TaskIsImportant = false;

class _TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build

return MaterialApp(
    title: "To-Do List V2",
    home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("To-Do List V2"),
        ),
        body: Flex(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter title of task to be added"),
                    onChanged: (taskTextField) {
                      setState(() {
                        TaskTextField = taskTextField;
                        print(TaskTextField);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                ),
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("Important"),
                  activeColor: Colors.blue,
                  value: TaskIsImportant,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      TaskIsImportant = !TaskIsImportant;
                      print(TaskIsImportant);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Text(
                  "Tip: Tap on your task to remove it",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(117, 10, 117, 5),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Icon(Icons.add),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (TaskIsImportant) {
                              taskTextList.add("❗️$TaskTextField");
                              //taskTitleList.add(TaskDetailField);
                            } else {
                              taskTextList.add(TaskTextField);
                              //taskTitleList.add(TaskDetailField);
                            }
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Icon(Icons.done_all),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            taskTextList = [];
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var title = taskTextList[index];
                      padding:
                      EdgeInsets.all(16.0);

                      return Dismissible(
                        key: Key(title[index]),
                        onDismissed: (direction) {
                          setState(() {
                            taskTextList.remove(title);
                          });
                        },
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            title,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: taskTextList.length,
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

When I create four listTiles in the emulator, two errors are given as follows

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following RangeError was thrown building:
flutter: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 4
```

I hope someone can tell me what is wrong with my code. I am running on flutter version 1.3.10. Thanks in advance.

Also to the person that needs more code, here is the full code of main.dart. Hope this will help you find my errors

Comment: Add the code where you are adding values in 'title' array and in 'taskTextList' array.

Comment: Alright I have added all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `title[index]` but saving the value in title as `title = taskTextList[index]` which is not an array. So, you are getting range error.

Comment: After changing title[index] to taskTextList[index], I get a new error called:
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building Dismissible-[<'sss'>](dirty, dependencies:
flutter: [Directionality], state: _DismissibleState#6a06e(tickers: tracking 2 tickers)):
flutter: A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.
flutter: Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible
flutter: widget from the application once that handler has fired.